# Will cancelling a future from ScheduledExecutorService free the Runnable instance?

Tags: java, android

If I cancel a future from ScheduledExecutorService, will the Runnable instance be removed from the executor immediately? Or is it still queued in the executor till the Runnable is expired. The code is like below. I am concerned about memory leak caused by the anonymous Runnable class instance.

```
mScheduledFuture = mScheduledExecutorService.schedule(
    new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        doSomething();
      }
    },
    MAX_DURATION_MINUTES,
    TimeUnit.MINUTES);

......
mScheduledFuture.cancel(false);
```

Comment: What implementation of `ScheduledExecutorService`? When you looked at its source code, what wasn't clear about the behavior?

Comment: When you tried it, what happened?

Comment: I took a look at ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor source code. Seems that it will hold the Runnable till it expires. I am not sure, so I am asking here. I didn't try it. I just wonder whether I can get a quick answer here. Otherwise I have to try it.